# Poder copiar contenido de un Label python

Tags: python, tkinter

simplemente me gustaría saber como configurar un "Label" para poder copiar contenido, todo esto es en "tkinter"

```
textoLabel=StringVar()
lbl=Label(raiz, font=("Arial", 14), textvariable=textoLabel)
lbl.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=(20,0), pady=(30,0))
```

la idea es poder seleccionar el contenido de un "label" así para posteriormente copiarlo

Answer (score 1):

Podrias utilizar un widget de texto deshabilitado de la siguiente forma:

```
from tkinter import *

window = Tk()

txt = Text(window, height=1)
txt.insert(1.0, "Mi texto para copiar")
txt.pack()

txt.configure(bg=window.cget('bg'), relief="flat")

txt.configure(state="disabled")

mainloop()
```

Comment: te he puesto un fragmento del código, es solamente un "label" pero es de ahí de donde quiero copiar la información al porta-papeles